# Entity Linq search List with List

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have a route which looks like: `?author=dog,cat,chicken`
What I'm trying to do is get the list of authors I got from the GET request and search through the Authors Table with the list I received. How will I be able to do that?

In My view I have:

```
public ActionResult Index(string author= null)
{
    var authors= author.Split(',');
    var data = db.ComicAuthors.Where(i => i.User.UserName.Contains(authors)); //ERROR HERE
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try reversing your logic, the user name will never contain a list of strings, however a list of string may contain the UserName:

```
public ActionResult Index(string author= null)
{
    var authors= author.Split(',');
    var data = db.ComicAuthors.Where(i => authors.Contains(i.User.UserName));
    return View();
}
```

*Note, you may need to pull all ComicAuthors first, as you might get a "Expression cannot be converted to a SQL expression" type error message.

```
    public ActionResult Index(string author= null)
    {
        var authors= author.Split(',');
        var data = db.ComicAuthors.ToList().Where(i => authors.Contains(i.User.UserName)); 
//May want to actually send data back to view
        return View(data);
    }
```

**Addendum**

If you want to check for the case that there are no authors identified, just do a quick boolean check on the author string:

```
    public ActionResult Index(string author= null)
    {
        var data = db.ComicAuthors.ToList()
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(author)){
            var authors= author.Split(',');
            data = data.Where(i => authors.Contains(i.User.UserName)); 
        }
        //May want to actually send data back to view
        return View(data);
    }
```

Comment: Quick second question, how can I reuse the query and make it where it gets all the Comic Authors if they don't put in anything for the authors?

Comment: @MohamadBataineh - updated to address your additional question

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that you can just split it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = db.ComicAuthors.Where(i => authors.Contains(i.User.UserName));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public ActionResult Index(string author= null)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(author))
          return View(db.ComicAuthors);

    var authors= author.Split(',');
    return View(db.ComicAuthors.Where(i => authors.Any(a=> a == i.User.UserName)));

}
```

Comment: Quick second question, how can I reuse the query and make it where it gets all the Comic Authors if they don't put in anything for the authors?